# JGraph - overriding cell drag

Tags: java, jgrapht

This is quite a long shot, I know it's a question about a very specific package.

I'm trying to stop nodes from dragging into a certain area of the graph.

I have written code to detect when the mouse is dragged over a node,  however it is a bit of a hack. I am trying to get the node that the mouse is dragging and its XY co-ordinates but have no idea how to do it.

I can't find any methods to override this, the marquee handler doesn't get called for a node drag. I'm looking at overriding the BasicUI class, but don't know

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here??

Comment: I'm trying to split the graph into two and not allow nodes from one side to be dragged past a certain point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off posting at the [JGraph forum](http://forum.jgraph.com).

Comment: This accepted answer became obsolete since 7th June 2013, see http://forum.jgraph.com/questions/6404/forum-jgraph-com-is-closed